# Code does not return if the condition is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, web-services

I need to validate if the user's provided information is in the database, i've tried to enter the correct condition and its not working it returns an error that it cannot be found on the database. Can you check my code and tell me what's going on? , I tried to debug it but the foreach loop continue to loop and does not go to if (isexist) statement

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        token = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtUsername.Text.ToString() + txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), "MD5");
        try
        {
            bool isExist = false;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = startService.getAllUsersWithoutFilter();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                    string userName = dRow["UserName"].ToString();
                    string acctNo = dRow["AccountNumber"].ToString();
                    string question = dRow["SecretQuestion"].ToString();
                    string answer = dRow["SecretAnswer"].ToString();

                    if (userName == txtUsername.Text.ToString() && acctNo == txtAcctNo.Text.ToString() && question == cboQuestion.Text.ToString() &&  answer == txtAnswer.Text.ToString())
                    {
                        isExist = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isExist = false;
                    }

                }

                if (isExist)
                {
                    startService.sendTokenizer(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), token);
                    //update database to change password to standard password
                    startService.inserUserActivity(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), "Password Reset Request", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
                    startService.requestReset(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), token);

                    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblMessage.Text = "<br>We have sent an email to you for the instructions to reset your password. Please check your email.";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    this.lblMessage.Text = "<br><br>Error - Information cannot be found. Please check and try again. Make sure all the fields are correct.";
                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lblError.Text = "There was an error occured while processing your request. Please try again later.";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all you need is to break out of your foreach loop when you set isExist to true.

```
if (userName == txtUsername.Text.ToString() && acctNo == txtAcctNo.Text.ToString() && question == cboQuestion.Text.ToString() &&  answer == txtAnswer.Text.ToString())
{
    isExist = true;
    break; //Found it, so stop looking.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Joel's right about a direct answer to your question.

I would add that you should reconsider loading the entire users table and iterating through it on the web server.  Why not just try to select a matching row from the database?  If you get a match, the credentials were valid.  If not, they were not valid.

Comment: +1 - Definitely a good idea to not load the entire table and utilize the power of the database to find the matching row for validation.

Answer (score 0):

@Dhenn: you need to make following changes in your code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    token = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtUsername.Text.ToString() + txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), "MD5");
    try
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = startService.getAllUsersWithoutFilter();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                string userName = dRow["UserName"].ToString();
                string acctNo = dRow["AccountNumber"].ToString();
                string question = dRow["SecretQuestion"].ToString();
                string answer = dRow["SecretAnswer"].ToString();

                if (userName == txtUsername.Text.ToString() && acctNo == txtAcctNo.Text.ToString() && question == cboQuestion.Text.ToString() &&  answer == txtAnswer.Text.ToString())
                {
                     // if exist execute following code

                    startService.sendTokenizer(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), token);
                //update database to change password to standard password
                startService.inserUserActivity(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), "Password Reset Request", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
                startService.requestReset(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), txtAcctNo.Text.ToString(), token);

                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                lblMessage.Text = "<br>We have sent an email to you for the instructions to reset your password. Please check your email.";
                }
                else
                {
                  // id not exist then execute following code

                   this.lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                this.lblMessage.Text = "<br><br>Error - Information cannot be found. Please check and try again. Make sure all the fields are correct.";
                }

            }              

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "There was an error occured while processing your request. Please try again later.";
    }

}
```